# android-getting error (No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0000000a)

Tags: java, android

I am using listView and custom arrayadaptor(which contains 3 text views and one integer value) while i am setting text using `setText` and calling method which returns integer. I am linking custom array adaptor and word file thanks.

I am getting error only when calling method which returns value of integer using `setText` method.

```
  public class Word {

        private static final int dollar = 10;
        private static final String buttonNAME = "ADD TO CART";

        //@var price var used for price description
        private int m Price;
        //@var mItemName var used for displaying item
        private String mItemName;

        //@constructor used to assign dag to the var

        public Word(int mPrice, String mItemName)
        {
            this.mPrice = mPrice;
            this.mItemName = mItemName;

        }

        public int getmPrice()
        {
            return mPrice;
        }

        public String getmItemName(){
            return mItemName;
        }

       public int getdollar()throws Exception{
            return dollar ;
            }
        public String getButtonnName(){
            return buttonNAME ;
        }
        }
```

customadapter

```
    class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {



        WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> items){

            super(context,0,items);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)  {
            // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            View listItemView = convertView;
            if(listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        list_items, parent, false);
            }

            // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
            Word currentPosition= getItem(position);

            // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name

            // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
            TextView itemTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listitems_item);
            // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
            // set this text on the number TextView


            if (currentPosition != null) {
                itemTextView.setText(currentPosition.getmItemName());
            }


            TextView dollarTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listitems_dollor);
            // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
            // set this text on the number TextView

            try {
                if (currentPosition != null)
                    dollarTextView.setText(currentPosition.getdollar());

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.getStackTrace();
                Log.v("coffe","satya");
            }



            Button buttoName = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listitems_addcart);

            if (currentPosition != null) {
                buttoName.setText(currentPosition.getButtonnName());
            }
            TextView priceTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_items_price);
            try {
                if (currentPosition != null)
                    priceTextView.setText(currentPosition.getmPrice());

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.getStackTrace();
                Log.v("coffe","satya");
            }


            return listItemView;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return value of integer using `setText` method, you need to use `setText(xxx+"");`

**Example**

```
 priceTextView.setText(currentPosition.getmPrice()+"");
```

Comment: what must i place in the cottations i mean after +

Comment: put `""` enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Integer.toString(currentPosition.getmPrice());
```

Or this:

```
String.valueOf(currentPosition.getmPrice());
```